# Difference between generate an entity data model in EF4 and EF6

Tags: entity-framework

Before I used `EF4` to generate my `entity data model` from an existing `database`. I can do `CRUD operations` on every generated `entity`, because the entities context class with all the methods is automatically generated. Now I have upgraded my project to `EF6`, deleted the files created by the `EF4 data mode`l wizard and generated it again using `EF6 data model wizard`. Now I get a `T4 template` file with a context class below it, a T4 template file with for every entity a class with code, a empty designer file and an edmx diagram file. But there are no methods such as `AddObject, DeleteObject, SaveChanges` generated. How can they be generated as it did before with `EF4?`

Comment: It's difficult to tell without seeing the situation. I would mess around with test projects just to see you can generate the context successfully. If so, compare with your master project to see what's gone wrong.

Answer (score 1):

EF6 should still generate a context for you. It provides the mentioned methods. Are you sure you just missed in amongs all the .tt files?

EDIT: Also, make sure you have all the proper references to EF. There might be a compiler warning indicating a problem.

Comment: Yes check it hasn't ended up in a different namespace.

Comment: I can make an instance of my model. But when I type a dot after the instance, intelligence only shows entities for every table from my database. This is because the generated context class only contains public virtual DbSet for every entity. Nowhere I can find the mentioned methods.

Comment: When installing EF6 the references EntityFramework and EntityFramework .SqlServer are automatically added. I have also reference to System.Data. When I'm generating the entity data model, there is no  compiler warning indicating a problem.

Comment: Thanks to everyone, especially LueTim. The methods are generated, but some are a bit differently named.